# Show/hide content using jquery in multiple DIVs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a single page with, say 5 posts, all in the `#article`. Following is the jQuery code used to toggle hide/show:

```
$(".click-show-more").click(function () {
    if($(".content").hasClass("show-more")) {
        $(this).text("(Show Less)");
    } else {
        $(this).text("(Show More)");
    }
    $(".content").toggleClass("show-more");
});
```

The `HTML` structure is :

```
<div class="article">
    <div class="content show-more">Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. 

Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
    </div>
    <div class="click-show-more">(Show More)</div>
</div>
```

Now, I have the above structure, 5-6 times on a single page, and whenever I click `Show More`, all the 5-6 posts expand.

How do I modify my code to expand only that particular post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
$(".content").hasClass("show-more")
```

to

```
$(this).closest('.article').find('.content').hasClass("show-more")
```

Your click should only affect the `content` of the particular article. So use the `this` context to your advantage.

Also this line

```
$(".content").toggleClass("show-more");
```

should be

```
$(this).closest('.article').find('.content').toggle();
```

Unless `.show-more {  display: none }` is already defined.

**Code**

```
$(".click-show-more").click(function () {
    var $closestContent = $(this).closest('.article').find('.content');

    if($closestContent.hasClass("show-more")) {
        $(this).text("(Show Less)");
    } else {
        $(this).text("(Show More)");
    }
    $closestContent.toggleClass('show-more');
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upkdM/1/)**

Comment: That's because you need to change the toggle to the right div as well.

Comment: @PalakArora.. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding any div with class `content`, you need to find the one within the same `article` div.

So it would look something like this:

```
$(".click-show-more").click(function () {
    var content = $(this).closest('.article').find('.content');
    if(content.hasClass("show-more")) {
        $(this).text("(Show Less)");
    } else {
        $(this).text("(Show More)");
    }
    content.toggleClass("show-more");
});
```

What's actually happening is we're taking the div that was clicked on:

```
$(this)
```

Finding the closest parent that has the `article` class:

```
$(this).closest('.article')
```

And then finding any children of that `article` div that have the `content` class:

```
$(this).closest('.article').find('.content')
```